# Increasing Bootstrap Progressbar on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with a single progress bar and one button.

I can get the progressbar to have a set value on Pageload, but I can't get it to increase over time using the button. I tried using HTMl onClick and jQuery .click(function(){ to no avail, been trying to do this for the past 2 hours and I gave up.

The progressbar value is set using the width% in the second div.

HTML:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active" style="width:400px;">
<div class="progress-bar" width="40%"></div>
</div>
<button id="code" type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="width:400px;">Generate Code</button>
```

Would like to do this without needing to install plugins.

tl;dr

I need to get a bootstrap progress bar to increase over time upon button click event.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the width of the progress-bar element

```
//this sets a random width
$('.progress-bar').width((Math.random() * 100) + '%')
```